# qtranslate is not working properly 

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I have installed [qtranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) in my local, it does not show the translated content, so there are two question if anybody have used this plugin.

1. do i need to put the translated text by my self or it[plugin] does automatically?
2. do i need to make changes in php file of the plugin to get the all automatic transnational.

the [plugin site](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) claims that,when the plugin is activated the dashboard will look like this

[image]

and this is what i am  getting on my local system

[image]

and when i see the front page it was supposed to translate all the english text to chines but it's not doing the same.

[image]

so if any one have used this plugin please clear my doubts and help me activating this plugin properly please advise may be i am wrong some where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The plugin doesn't automatically provide translation - you have to fill it in yourself.  However, there is a service you can use to get your translations:

> With qTranslate 2.3, a new feature called "qTranslate Services" have been added. So what does it do?
>
> Well, with qTranslate Services, qTranslate can finally do what the name suggest: Translations. Translation with qTranslate Services is as easy as two mouse clicks. Simply enable it under "Settings" on "Language Management".
>
> So what's the difference between qTranslate Services and other translation plugins? Well, qT not only supports free machine translation, but also professional human translation! The Services are provided by Web-Translations, where Ford, MTV and many other companies get their translations from.
>
> Feel free to test the service and report any problems here.

2) <s>No, no need to do php coding to 'make it work'</s>

**Update**

Apparently the original machine translation option is no longer available.  [Here are two options from the support forum](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=406) to add google translate output when a manual translation is not available.  One involves editing php code, the other css and javascript.

Comment: plugin was misunderstood by me i thought it will translate the headings automatically but based on your answer I am guessing it wont do such things

Comment: It does work with Google's API and Bing's API so I would think you can use Google Translate to do this. See http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/