# wordpress qtranslate editor text is not working

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, plugin-qtranslate

I have installed qtranslate on my wordpress site, it all works fine, but sometimes the content editor does not show the text, When I force refresh the page a few times (Ctrl + r) ***eventually the text shows up***.

I was going to put images here to explain it but, this post already has the images I would put on, (**however the questions differ**) [qtranslate is not working properly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64690/qtranslate-is-not-working-properly)

I have deactivated all of the plugins, and this problem it's still there, I have tried alot of other things to

**Error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setup' of undefined
Line: 303, qtranslate_javascript.php

$q_config['js']['qtrans_hook_on_tinyMCE'] = "
qtrans_hook_on_tinyMCE = function(id) {

tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[id].setup = function(ed) {
    ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {
        if (!ed.isHidden())  {
            qtrans_save(switchEditors.pre_wpautop(o.content));
        }
    });
};
ed = new tinymce.Editor(id, tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[id]);
    ed.render();
}
";
```

**Console Logging ID:**

```
qtrans_textarea_content post.php:467
qtrans_textarea_acf_settings
```

**Other notes**

I have also tried to add the `try{} catch(e){}` to avoid the script from breaking down, it does not seem to help at all, I have run out of options and I really need some help with this

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have found a great post which solves this issue,

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-qtranslate-problems-displaying-in-the-edit?replies=21#post-3160564

The issue is on qtranslate_javascript.php line 225

**Replace**

```
var waitForTinyMCE = window.setInterval(function() {
                if(typeof(tinyMCE) !== 'undefined' && typeof(tinyMCE.get2) == 'function' && tinyMCE.get2('content')!=undefined) {
                    content=jQuery('#content').val();
                    tinyMCE.get2('content').remove();
                    jQuery('#content').val(content);
                    window.clearInterval(waitForTinyMCE);
                }
            }, 250);
```

**WITH:** Only change the `250` to `500` :) this should solve the problem...

```
var waitForTinyMCE = window.setInterval(function() {
                if(typeof(tinyMCE) !== 'undefined' && typeof(tinyMCE.get2) == 'function' && tinyMCE.get2('content')!=undefined) {
                    content=jQuery('#content').val();
                    tinyMCE.get2('content').remove();
                    jQuery('#content').val(content);
                    window.clearInterval(waitForTinyMCE);
                }
            }, 500);
```